# Chrome driver with Proxy Authentication Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried to run chrome driver with Proxy Authentication using python selenium.
There are many questions and answers, similar to my case.
However, they didn't solve my case.
Please help me if you know the correct answer.
Python - 3.6
Chrome - 98.0.4
I followed this url: stackoverflow.com/questions/29983106/how-can-i-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chrome-web-driver-using-pyth
It seems to work for others, but not work for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import zipfile

manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            port: parseInt(xxx)
          },
          bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "xxxxxxxx",
            password: "xxxxxxxx"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
"""


pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
    zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
    zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

co = Options()
co.add_argument("--start-maximized")
co.add_extension(pluginfile)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),  chrome_options=co)
driver.get("http://www.google.com.br")
```

[image]